# Getting a handle on the listboxitem in RelayCommand method

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

This is for WP7. 
I have a button in a listbox itemtemplate. In the associated ViewModel, I have RelayCommand, which I have bound to the Click event of the Button (using MVVMLight EventToCommand). All I want is to pass in the ListItem of the ListBox when the button is clicked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use in xaml `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` which will pass your selected ListItem to the command

then in view model

```
private RelayCommand<ListItem> _command;

public RelayCommand<ListItem> Command
{
    get
    {
        return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(Method));
    }
}

public void Method(ListItem item)
{
    ...
}
```